# why glibc fcntl is implemented as this?

Tags: glibc, fcntl, variadic-functions

all;I'm looking the glibc source code now;i have a question is this:

```
int fcntl(int fd, int cmd, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, cmd);
    void* arg = va_arg(ap, void*);
    va_end(ap);
    return __fcntl64(fd, cmd, arg);
}
```

why this ???!!!

```
fcntl(fd,cmd); // is this a trouble?
fcntl(fd,cmd,i/*int type*/); // and this?
```

Thanks,anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is the most portable way of doing that. The system [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) could (and sometimes does, e.g. [x86-64 Linux ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf)) define different [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) for variadic and for fixed arity functions.

Probably, older libc versions just defined `int fcntl(int fd, int cmd, void*arg)`  and that usually worked (at least if `arg` was not used and not accessed when not needed), perhaps on 32 bits x86 with an ABI requiring every argument to be passed on the stack. But on 64 bits x86-64 some arguments are passed by registers (and which ones and how may differ for variadic functions).

Of course [`fcntl(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) and [`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)  can be called with both two and three arguments.

If you call `fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &mylock)` it should be ok, but if you forgot the third argument with `fcntl(fd,F_SETLK)` it becomes  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and you *might* get some segmentation violation (but probably not). Be [*very scared*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of undefined behavior.

You could compile some sample code with `gcc -Wall -O -fverbose-asm -S`  to get the generated assembler code (look into the emitted `.s` assembler file with a pager or editor) and figure out, after reading your ABI specification, how calls are really done.

Comment: when called with`fcntl(fd,cmd);`;will `va_arg(ap,void*)` SIGSEGV or something wrong else?; Thanks!

Comment: @qwertimg Apparently, on platforms that run glibc and support fcntl, and with the compiler version and options used to compile glibc, it won't. You still shouldn't do that in your code, because you might not be on one of those platforms, or you might be using a different compiler.